# Append columns of pandas dataframe based on a regex

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes which I would like to append based on a regex. If the value in a 'code' column of df1 matches (eg. R93) with the 'ICD_CODE' of df2(eg. R93), append the 'code' column value to df2.

```
df1
code
R93.2
S03


df2
ICD_CODE    ICD_term                        MDR_code    MDR_term    
R93.1       Acute abdomen                   10000647    Acute abdomen   
K62.4       Stenosis of anus and rectum     10002581    Anorectal stenosis
S03.1       Hand-Schüller-Christian disease 10053135    Hand-Schueller-Christian disease
```

The expected output is:

```
code    ICD_CODE    ICD_term                        MDR_code    MDR_term    
R93.2   R93.1       Acute abdomen                   10000647    Acute abdomen   
S03     S03.1       Hand-Schüller-Christian disease 10053135    Hand-Schueller-Christian disease
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Strictly speaking, I don't think Pandas supports doing this with a proper regex. But the answer below gets close to hacking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the left part (before dot) of each code columns as the `merge` key:

```
out = (df1.merge(df2, left_on=df1['code'].str.split('.').str[0], 
                right_on=df2['ICD_CODE'].str.split('.').str[0])
          .drop(columns='key_0'))
print(out)

# Output
    code ICD_CODE                         ICD_term  MDR_code                          MDR_term
0  R93.2    R93.1                    Acute abdomen  10000647                     Acute abdomen
1    S03    S03.1  Hand-Schüller-Christian disease  10053135  Hand-Schueller-Christian disease
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible *solution* would be to use `process.extractOne` from [fuzzywuzzy](/questions/tagged/fuzzywuzzy).

```
#pip install fuzzywuzzy
from fuzzywuzzy import process
​
out = (df1.assign(matched_code=df1["code"].apply(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, df2["ICD_CODE"])[0]))
          .merge(df2, left_on="matched_code", right_on="ICD_CODE")
          .drop(columns="matched_code")
       )
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)
​
    code ICD_CODE                         ICD_term  MDR_code                          MDR_term
0  R93.2    R93.1                    Acute abdomen  10000647                     Acute abdomen
1    S03    S03.1  Hand-Schüller-Christian disease  10053135  Hand-Schueller-Christian disease
```